# Local Db failure on initialization of template

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

I'm trying to setup a startup template to play around with boilerplate and see what it could potentially offer and I'm running into issues setting up my local database.

I've tried the core startup template download as well as MVC 5 and they've both given me the same issue so far. I'll open up the solution in VS 2017, clean the solution, rebuild, enter Package Manager Console and execute Update-Database on the EntityFramework project and I get this error on both projects,

```
ClientConnectionId:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
Error Number:2,State:0,Class:20

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing 
a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. 
Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured 
to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - 
Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
```

I'm having a hard time understanding what this might be indicating. I'm pretty sure I've been able to use my local db in other projects recently.

Comment: Did you change the connection string in [appsettings.json](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template/blob/master/aspnet-core/src/AbpCompanyName.AbpProjectName.Migrator/appsettings.json)?

Comment: @aaron No, I still have the connection string setup to "Default": "Server=localhost; Database=TestBoilerPlateDb; Trusted_Connection=True;" Should that be different?

Comment: Yes, you need to set up an empty local db. You can try SQLServer.

Comment: Did you try create empty TestBoilerPlateDb database on MSSQL server?

Comment: Looks like this was just my inexperience on hooking up my local database. I was able to boot up a new project with authentication and check how VS was configuring my connection string to my local db and mimic that. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: You're welcome! Posted it as an answer :)

Comment: post your answer or accept @aaron answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set up an empty database and provide a valid connection string in [appsettings.json](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template/blob/master/aspnet-core/src/AbpCompanyName.AbpProjectName.Migrator/appsettings.json).

You can use [Microsoft's SQL Server](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-downloads).